# is it possible to debug javascript on chrome using ie tab view?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, debugging, tabs

I need to find solution for old project that build to work on ie5.5 to work on chrome.

when i open it on chrome and see the web in ie tab most of stuff not working there but using ie tab make it properly  better.  To fix more bugs i found there i tried to set breakpoint on js to see what make problems, when it happens its not stop on breakpoint.

The code of page that i see in the developer tool is the chrome cover code

I tried to found solution to this problem but i cant find anything that can help me to go out of this problem.
there is tool that created for that?

---edit

The only attitude i found to this is here
https://c.getsatisfaction.com/ietab/topics/how_to_debug_ie_tab_i_am_not_able_to_see_chromes_developer_tools_if_i_press_f12

that i cant debug the code.i can debug there only the ie container code...
there is a way to debug the inner js code there?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the F12 tools in a Chrome Tab. You could try to connect with Visual Studio (2013) you would first need to identify the process to attach to and then select 'Script' from the debug engine type and then try attach. You may also need to enable script debugging (other) via:

`Internet Options -> Advanced -> (Uncheck) Disable Script Debugging (Other)`

Then in the Visual Studio attach to process dialog you should see 'Script' listed in the type column of the process for the IE tab (in Chrome).

Answer (score 0):

If you navigate to the Developer tools section of the docs they state that:

> All error messages are displayed in the Chrome error console. Any error message that happens within the page that is loaded in IE Tab will be prefixed with "IE: " in the Chrome console.

[Here are the docs if you require more information](https://www.ietab.net/ie-tab-documentation)

Answer (score -3):

You could try debugging the JavaScript in IE using IE's F12 developer tools.

Comment: I want to run chrome click on ie tab view and then debug it.  Try it and see that you cant, you can see just some ie container div and there is no way to see my js code